# How do you use then call backs and promises

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I need help with promises and `then` callbacks.
I have tried reading guides but don't understand them.

```
var lastMessage = msg.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 2 }).then(messages => {
  return messages.last();
})
```

This returns `Promise { < pending > }`.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve with the code, other than just straight up "understanding it"?

Comment: Could you add information about any error related to the code being executed?

Comment: i am trying to get the 2nd last message's content stored into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then()` statements don't make the program wait for them to be completed, they just execute their code after the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) they're attached to is resolved.
You can either decide to move the rest of the code inside that `.then()` statement (but it'll get really messy) or use `async/await`.
If you are inside a function, you can declare that as an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function): that allows you to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword inside it. [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) makes the program wait for a Promise to resolve, and instead of a Promise it returns the value that you would use in the `.then()` function.
Here's an example:

```
client.on('message', async () => {
  // You can do everything you would normally do here
  // Using the 'async' keyword allows you to later user 'await'
  var lastMessage = await msg.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 2 }).then(messages => {
    return messages.last();
  });
});
```

*Partially adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149054/7133466) (also mine)*